# Which layout is suitable for a live cryptocurrency news feed?

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, master-details, newsfeed, cryptocurrency

- I am trying to build a live cryptocurrency news feed and this is a new domain + I am new to UX

  - I researched a bit and seem to find a few patterns on how these can be built.
  - Which layout would serve the purpose optimally?
  - I researched a few guys to see what layouts are there and this is what I found

**1) Cryptopanic.com**

[image]

- Has a 2 pane layout with list details view
- On the mobile, either the list or details are shown
- So many buttons on top? Are those buttons really needed?
- Monospaced font for news?
- Like Dislike ...buttons at the top seem to be sticky if you scroll the news on mobile? Is this required

**2) CoinSpectator.com**
[image]

- Same 2 pane layout
- Font seems far better
- Right pane seems smaller than left one? What do you think should be the size? Should the user be able to change it?
- Adds images to the news making things more interesting I guess
- Has a READ FULL button at the bottom to take you the news site whereas Cryptopanic has KEPT the title clickable? What to do here?

**3) Faws**
[image]

- Instead of a 2 pane layout, uses an expandable list
- No option to like dislike stuff, other 2 had them

**4) Cryptopys.com**
[image]

- Very different from the rest, shows a screen on right pane
- Detail news opens in a chat popup sort of window
- Has a question at the bottom of each news article saying what do you think with again way too many buttons

**So based on these, here are my questions**

- 2 pane layout or expandable list
- How big should each pane be? 50 50%, 75 25% customizable?
- Should the links in the list on the left be clickable or should they merely show names? Cryptopanic has them clickable but rest merely show names
- Are all those buttons needed? can it be cut down to Likes Dislikes Bullish and Bearish? Instead of adding a button for FUD or Shilling would a person not click Dislike?

  - Should the link the right detail be clickable (Cryptopanic) or should there be a button at the bottom saying Read Full (CoinSpectator)
  - Should the left section show anything about likes dislikes or does it only have time, title, website name and tags?
  - Should the tags on left be clickable?

Any suggestions are super appreciated

Comment: To answer these questions you really need to talk to some of your target users and, without showing them any layouts, ask them about what they want to see, what would drive them to use your product. Then incorporate those ideas into a prototype and test that with new target users by giving them tasks to complete - Then you should be able to see what works and what doesn't. Then you tweak the design as do it over again until you reach an acceptable success rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a LEAN UX perspective (check this link https://www.justinmind.com/blog/complete-guide-to-lean-ux/), I would go with the minimum of elements (MVP) in the beginning and follow the feedback of your users to add/redesign elements.
I support the previous comment to prototype and test with users by giving tasks to complete. It is important not to test many hypotheses at the same time. You have lots of questions, so you need to prioritize them for testing.
It will help if you read the user's feedback from the mentioned layouts. You might find some strong usability issues that you aren't aware of right now.

Keep in mind that doing things differently than others might be the key differentiator of your product.

Comment: Hi Mirela, please summarise the relevant information from the hyperlink and quote them in your answers, because there is a big chance of links getting stale in the future. Thank you have fun.

Comment: One more thing is that you have mentioned `previous comment`. 1. But the order of comments might change in the future. 2. Other users might not be aware of the previous comment. One good workaround could be, you can mention it like: @<<Firstname's>> comment :)